# Why I can't access to these node content using XPath?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I am pretty new in **XPath** and in **C#** and I have the following problem:

I have to parse this file: http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml

As you can see opening it in the browser this file have the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<cpe-list xmlns:meta="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2" xmlns:config="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1" xmlns:ns6="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns:scap-core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3" xmlns="http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0" xmlns:cpe-23="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/configuration_0.1.xsd http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0 http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary_2.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.3.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata_0.2.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3 http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary-extension_2.3.xsd">
  <generator>
    <product_name>National Vulnerability Database (NVD)</product_name>
    <product_version>2.22.0-SNAPSHOT (PRODUCTION)</product_version>
    <schema_version>2.3</schema_version>
    <timestamp>2014-03-05T05:13:33.550Z</timestamp>
  </generator>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:0.7">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 0.7</title>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:0.7:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.2.5">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.2.5</title>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.2.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.3.1">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.3.1</title>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>

  .............................................................
  .............................................................
  .............................................................

  <cpe-item name="cpe:/h:zyxel:p-660hw_t3:v2">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">ZyXEL P-660HW T3 Model v2</title>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:h:zyxel:p-660hw_t3:v2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
</cpe-list>
```

So now, using **XPath**, I have to obtain the list of all  tag (excluding the first  tag situated as first tag into my  tag

In my code I have something like it:

```
       XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();    // Represent an XML document
       document.Load(sourceXML.FullName);       // Loads the XML document from the specified stream

       // Add the namespaces:
       XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns6", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("cpe-23", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-extension/2.3");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("meta", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe-dictionary-metadata/0.2");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("scap-core", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.3");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
       nsmgr.AddNamespace("config", "http://scap.nist.gov/schema/configuration/0.1");



       /* nodeList is the collection that contains all the <cpe-item> tag that are
         * inside the root <cpe-list> tag in the XML document: 
         */
       XmlNodeList nodeList;
       nodeList = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:cpe-list/ns:cpe-item", nsmgr);
       long conta = 0;
```

So I am using this line to select all the  tag that are into the  tag:

```
nodeList = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:cpe-list/ns:cpe-item", nsmgr);
```

It seems to work but I am not sure if it is correct because when I look into using the Visual Studio Debugger it say to me that my **XmlNodeList nodeList** contains: 80588 element (the file is very big but it seems to me to much element !!!)

Another doubt is related to the use of the **ns** namespace that is into my previouse code (this is not my code, I have to work on it).

Why in the previous code there is the **ns** namepace ahead the **cpe-list** and **cpe-item** if in the XML code to parse I smply have something like:

```
  <cpe-item name="cpe:/a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.3.1">
    <title xml:lang="en-US">1024cms.org 1024 CMS 1.3.1</title>
    <cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:a:1024cms:1024_cms:1.3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>
  </cpe-item>
```

that don't begin with **ns** namespace? Why is it used?

The last question is about how can I access to the **title** inner text content?

I am trying to do something like this but in this way can't work:

```
XmlNodeList nodeList;
nodeList = document.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//ns:cpe-list/ns:cpe-item", nsmgr);
long conta = 0;

DataModel.Vulnerability.CPE currentCPE;

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    // Access to the name ATTRIBUTE of the <cpe-item> tag:
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0:N0}] CPE: {1}  Title: {2}", conta, node.Attributes["name"].Value, node.FirstChild.FirstChild.Value));

    // Access to the <title> tag content:
    //Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("[{0:N0}] Title: {1}  Title: {2}", conta, node.SelectSingleNode("./title", nsmgr)));
    XmlNode titleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("./title", nsmgr);

    conta++;
 }
```

When this code is executed I have no problem to access to the **name** attributes of the current cpe element into my list but I can't access to the content of the  tag because when execute this line:

```
 XmlNode titleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("./title", nsmgr);
```

it return that the value is **null**

What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: You should ask each question as a separate question. And your first problem about having seemingly too many results, I suggest you check that yourself to be sure you have too many before you ask a question about it

Comment: What musefan said. Also you're confusing tags with elements which makes the question confusing. Refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your XPath looks fine given XML snippet posted in this question. It should return correct number of elements as far as I can see. Can't tell more than that, you should check further yourself.
2. Your XML has default namespace (`xmlns="....."`). All elements in XML without prefix considered in default namespace. But in XPath, all element without prefix considered has no namespace. In the end, that different paradigm of both platform requires you to define `ns` prefix that point to default namespace url for use in XPath statement.
3. Related to point 2. Remember that all element without prefix is in default namespace. So is `<title>` element. Hence you need to add `ns` prefix in the XPath statement : `./ns:title`
4. Ideally, **one post** has to contains no more than **one specific question**. Answering a bunch of questions in one post is rarely useful for future visitors, it is tend to confuse them instead. Remember that we are not only solving your problem here, but also trying to build knowledge-base that hopefully useful for others having similar problem.

Comment: tnx so much, in te future I will divide my multiple questions into multiple posts :-)